# 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new > OpenLayers.Layer.GML'

Tags: openlayers-2, kml

My OpenLayers map was working fine before, showing a KML overlay. Suddenly it broke. Now I see this error in my browser error console.

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new
>   OpenLayers.Layer.GML')

My code looks like this:

```
var kmllayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.GML("KML", "./my-kml-file.kml", 
   {    
    format: OpenLayers.Format.KML, 
    formatOptions: {
      extractStyles: true, 
      extractAttributes: true,
      maxDepth: 2
    }
   });
map.addLayer(kmllayer);
```

Answer (score 6):

Change it to look like this

```
var kmllayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
     strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
           protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "./my-kml-file.kml",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                    extractStyles: true, 
                    extractAttributes: true,
                    maxDepth: 2
          })
     })
})
```

OpenLayers.Layer.GML was deprecated and then removed in version 3.0 of OpenLayers which was released recently.  If you simply include the latest OpenLayers with script tag pointing like this...

```
<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
```

...then things can break when features are deprecated, though this shouldn't happen *too* often. An alternative is to download a particular version of the javascript library and host this yourself.

Comment: OpenLayers is on version 2.12, not 3. I would always use a local version, not only can you make sure things still work when there are upgrades but you can also customize your version of OpenLayers depending on what you want, potentially making your OpenLayers JS smaller and simpler.

Comment: Plus, you avoid bandwidth leeching :). Building your own OpenLayers JavaScript file with Python is quick and easy even on Windows machines, just don't try to use the wrong Python version like I did (that is, use Python 2.x and not 3.x)